# New repositories I add are never found?

Tags: repository, crunchbang

I'm running CrunchBang with the following output from `uname -a`

```
Linux sigh 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt2-1 (2014-12-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My `sources.list`

```
# Crunchbang
deb http://packages.crunchbang.org/waldorf waldorf main
deb-src http://packages.crunchbang.org/waldorf waldorf main

# Debian Wheezy
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main contrib non-free

# Debian Jessie
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main contrib non-free

# Debian Security
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

# Debian Backports
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main contrib non-free

# Debian Multimedia
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy main non-free

# Oracle Java
deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all
```

So whenever I add any new repository through `apt-add-repository` and run `apt-get update`, I get errors along the following format:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/conky-companions/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/conky-companions/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I figure it's because I'm asking for the `jessie/main` version, which does not exist in most packages(?) but I'm not sure how to change the sources.list to keep this from happening and avoid breaking my system anymore than it apparently is.

Does anyone know how I can keep it from fetching from `jessie/main`? Or explain to me exactly what's going on so I can get these repositories working?

Comment: The question is, how are you adding these repositories? `add-apt-repository`? These new repositories are likely saved in new files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Edit them to use an appropriate Ubuntu version (`trusty`, perhaps).

Comment: Yes that's how I'm adding them. So I need to edit each entry every time I add a new repository? Isn't there a way to fix this automatically when using add-apt-repository?

Answer (score 1):

`add-apt-repository` detects your distribution codename automatically and doesn't provide options to do so. It cannot, of course, magically match up a version of Debian to Ubuntu, and to make it to do so, you'll have to edit `/etc/lsb-release`, which may break other things. This is because `add-apt-repository` calls [`SoftwareProperties.add_source_from_shortcut`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-dev/software-properties/main/view/head:/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py#L722), which in turn uses [`aptsources.distro.get_distro()`](http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/aptsources.distro.html#aptsources.distro.get_distro) to determine the codename:

```
aptsources.distro.get_distro(id=None, codename=None, description=None, release=None)
Check the currently used distribution and return the corresponding distriubtion class that supports distro specific features.
If no paramter are given the distro will be auto detected via a call to lsb-release
```

<sup><sub>(No, that's not my spelling.)</sub></sup>

So, if you're feeling up to it, edit `/etc/lsb-release` and change `DISTRIB_CODENAME` to an appropriate version of Ubuntu (since that's the target of most Launchpad PPAs), such as `trusty`.

---

Or, you could construct the actual line. `ppa:username/ppa-name` translates to:

```
add-apt-repository https://ppa.launchpad.net/username/ppa-name/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc)
```

Of course, you'll replace `$(lsb_release -sc)` with `trusty`, etc. You'll also need to fetch the GPG key manually and add it. This also has the drawback that instead of creating a nice new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, the entry is added to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

---

Looks like you have to change both `DISTRIB_ID` and `DISTRIB_CODENAME`, so that their values match:

```
$ lsb_release -sc
trusty
$ sudo sed 's/trusty/wheezy/' -i /etc/lsb-release
$ lsb_release -sc                                
wheezy
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conky-companions/ppa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 91, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/wheezy
$ sudo sed 's/trusty/wheezy/;s/Ubuntu/Debian/' -i /etc/lsb-release
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conky-companions/ppa                

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~conky-companions/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp19qsp29e/secring.gpg' created
#...
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/conky-companions-ppa-wheezy.list 
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/conky-companions/ppa/ubuntu wheezy main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/conky-companions/ppa/ubuntu wheezy main
$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/conky-companions-ppa-wheezy.list 
$ sudo sed 's/wheezy/trusty/' -i /etc/lsb-release
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conky-companions/ppa                
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 91, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
#...
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Debian/trusty
$ sudo sed 's/wheezy/trusty/;s/Debian/Ubuntu/' -i /etc/lsb-release
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conky-companions/ppa                

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~conky-companions/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpnz_771l_/secring.gpg' created
#...
OK
```

Naturally, any repositories you added *before* this change would still need to be manually corrected.

Comment: It seems CrunchBang has it's own `lsb-release` that isn't hit(?) by it because it's called `lsb-release-crunchbang` instead. So you're saying I should make an `lsb-release` file to make apt-get believe I'm running on an ubuntu release instead of a CrunchBang one? Also, when aliasing the `lsb-release-crunchbang` as `lsb-release`, I get this error: `aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for CrunchBang/waldorf`

Comment: Update: I've added a new lsb-release with following contents: `DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=quantal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu quantal"` but I still get the same repository errors:
`W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/conky-companions/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/conky-companions/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found`

Comment: @BrianRodriguez so any new repositories you added don't use the new `lsb-release`? Can you test using the `lsb_release` command whether that file is read?